# In Apache Camel what does "route()" do in a restful declaration?

Tags: apache-camel

Trying to google "route" in relation to Camel is like trying to google "the". Browsing the docs and can't find it either, only an interface called Route.

Inherited some code that looks like

```
        rest("/someRoute")
        .description("Some description")
        .consumes("text/plain")
        .produces("text/plain")
        .post()
        .route()
        .to("direct:toSomewhere");
```

What does route() do? I have tried with and without route() and it doesn't seem to do anything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `.route` allows you to define new route(s) within your rest-definition. It can be handy if your route is short or if you just want to process/transform/validate the message in someway before sending it to your actual consumer endpoint.

**For example**

```java
rest("/someRoute")
    .id("someRoute")
    .description("Some description")
    .post()
        .consumes("text/plain")
        .produces("text/plain")
        .route()
            .routeId("someRoutePost")
            .process(new SomeMessageProcessor())
            .to("direct:toSomewhere")
        .end()
    .endRest()
    .get()
        .route()
            .routeId("someRouteGet")
            .setHeader(Exchange.HTTP_RESPONSE_CODE, constant(405))
            .setBody(constant("GET not allowed on this route"))
        .end()
    .endRest()
```

But if you just want to call direct consumer endpoint and do this stuff there instead you can do that.

it is up to ones preference really.

> thanks, I see if I wanted to say call .log() I would have to put .route() first

Yes. Camel uses [method-chaining](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Method_chaining) with its Java-DSL where something like this is often required. When defining Rest most methods return `RestDefinition` but if you look closely `.route` method returns `RouteDefition` instead.

To get back to `RestDefition` from route one can use `.endRest()` as the `.end()` in the example doesn't really do anything other than make it easier to see where to RouteDefition block ends.

---

**Update:** Note that this example is for Camel **3.14.0**. In Newer versions of Camel `route()` and `endRest()` methods have been Removed from RestDefition class. Example for Camel 3.18.1 can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73611198/16480631).

Comment: thanks, I see if I wanted to say call .log() I would have to put .route() first