# Apache Camel differences between rest() and from("rest:get")

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, rest, apache-camel

Good Morning!

These days I'm trying to learn how to use Apache Camel.
With a course on Udemy it was pretty simple to learn how to do standard operation in route.
Now I wish to learn the use of the Rest integration, but I don't understand the differences between the exposition of an endpoint with

```
rest("/someRoute")
                .consumes("application/json").produces("application/json")
                .get().outType(String.class);
```

or

```
from("rest:get:/rest-route/get-route")
                .routeId("ReceiverRoute")
                .transform().constant("Bye World")
                .log("${body}");
```

Can anyone explain which are the differences between them and which is the best way to expose the endpoint? Why?

I can't understand neither the construction of the rest() route and how to use the route() instruction.
I tried to work on this example in another stackoverflow post:

[In Apache Camel what does "route()" do in a restful declaration?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70744710/in-apache-camel-what-does-route-do-in-a-restful-declaration)

but the same route in my class is not correct and I can't understand why.

```
        rest("/someRoute")
            .id("someRoute")
            .description("Some description")
            .post()
                .consumes("text/plain")
                .produces("text/plain")
                .route()                       //HERE I have the error: Cannot resolve method 'route' in 'RestDefinition'
                    .routeId("someRoutePost")
                    .to("direct:toSomewhere")
                .end()
            .endRest()
            .get()
                .route()
                    .routeId("someRouteGet")
                    .setHeader(Exchange.HTTP_RESPONSE_CODE, constant(405))
                    .setBody(constant("GET not allowed on this route"))
                .end()
            .endRest();
```

I'm working with Springboot 2.7.3 and Camel 3.18.1 with these dependencies:

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.camel.springboot</groupId>
            <artifactId>camel-spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
            <version>${camel.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.camel.springboot</groupId>
            <artifactId>camel-http-starter</artifactId>
            <version>${camel.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.camel.springboot</groupId>
            <artifactId>camel-servlet-starter</artifactId>
            <version>${camel.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.camel.springboot</groupId>
            <artifactId>camel-rest-starter</artifactId>
            <version>${camel.version}</version>
        </dependency>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Can anyone explain which are the differences between them and which is the best way to expose the endpoint? Why?

The method above uses Camel [Rest-DSL](https://camel.apache.org/manual/rest-dsl.html) which allows you to define rest endpoints using java instead of fiddling URI Strings.

The method below uses [camel-rest](https://camel.apache.org/components/latest/rest-component.html) component which works almost identically except for the fact that you use URI strings to configure it. It's possible that Rest-DSL uses this under the hood.

The example you're referring to used camel version 3.14.0 but it seems both `.route()` and `endRest()` methods have been quietly removed from RestDefitinion which causes the exception `Cannot resolve method 'route' in 'RestDefinition`.

Instead of `route()` you should use `to("direct:endpointName")` instead. My guess is that developers wanted to move most of the routing logic away from the RestDSL to keep it clean.

**Here's example for Camel 3.18.1**

```java
// What I used to test this
restConfiguration()
    .component("undertow")
    .host("localhost")
    .port(8091);

// http://localhost:8091/api/hello
rest("/api")
    .description("Some description")
    .post("/hello")
        .consumes("text/plain")
        .produces("text/plain")
        .to("direct:someRoutePost")
    .get("/hello")
        .produces("text/plain")
        .to("direct:someRouteGet");

from("direct:someRouteGet")
    .routeId("someRouteGet")
    .setHeader(Exchange.HTTP_RESPONSE_CODE, constant(200))
    .setBody(constant("Hello world"));

from("direct:someRoutePost")
    .routeId("someRoutePost")
    .setHeader(Exchange.HTTP_RESPONSE_CODE, constant(405))
    .setBody(constant("POST not allowed on this route"));
```

Tested by generating project using maven `camel-archetype-spring-boot` archetype version `3.18.1`, added in following dependency.

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.camel.springboot</groupId>
    <artifactId>camel-undertow-starter</artifactId>
</dependency>
```